# Extract text with conditions in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have researched lot and couldn't find a regex where I can achieve the desired text with below conditions.

I have a huge paragraph of text, I want to extract text with certain conditions:

1. The extracted text should start with list of words. eg: Apple, Banana, Orange, Pineapple.
2. It should end with when any of the other 3 words is encountered and there is a preceding number.
3. The extraction should start only when there is a preceding number to it.

> Sample text:
>
> I have 2 apples in my bag and apples are great food toeat. you shud
>   eat apples daily. it is very good for health. 3 bananas are also good.
>   it reduces fat.

Below is the excepted output

> apples in my bag and apples are great......good for health.
>
> bananas are also good. it reduces fat

So, if there are 2 keywords present, I want 2 files to be created and so on.

**Update of what I tried:**

The regex which I tried is:

```
(?=(\d+)(\s?)apple)(.*)(?=\d+\s?banana:?s)
```

[Regex I tried](https://regex101.com/r/0DRayP/10)

I have 2 problems here:

1. In the extracted text I don't want the 1st number
2. How to make it dynamic as in if I have 4 words, I don't have to write that many combinations and if we are searching for apple the extracted text for that is saved in that variable

Python version: 3.5

**Can you please help me with a regex for this.**

Comment: If you are downvoting, please provide the duplicate question. I am happy to remove the question because I have done my analysis and I am new to regex

Comment: You are getting downvotes because you have not tried any code and expect the entire code to be written by someone else. Read about regex and put some effort into writing the code and then if you get stuck come back here and ask for the solution.

Comment: @serbia99: Added what I have tried till now

Comment: An out of context, single regexp is not _"... some effort into writing the code ...:_, at least not in my book.  Have you already read [mcve]?

Comment: To be honest, the whole thing is about a good regex and that is what I am trying and what I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this: `\d+\s*((?:Apple|Banana|Orange|Pineapple)s?\b[\s\S]*?)(?=$|\d+\s*(?:Apple|Banana|Orange|Pineapple)s?\b)`

See:

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9gijrh/4/)**

The code:

```
import re

regex = r"\d+\s*((?:Apple|Banana|Orange|Pineapple)s?\b[\s\S]*?)(?=$|\d+\s*(?:Apple|Banana|Orange|Pineapple)s?\b)"

test_str = "I have 2 apples in my bag and apples are great food toeat. you shud eat apples daily. it is very good for health. 3 bananas are also good. it reduces fat."

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for match in matches: print(match + "\n")
```

**[code demo](https://ideone.com/VWf6jQ)**

**Note**: I'm assuming you would want to stop matching on new line characters. If that is not the case, you may remove the `re.MULTILINE` flag so that `$` matches end of string.

Comment: It works great only problem is if I change my string to "I have 2 apples in my bag and 1 apple.....xx..." then it would give a match. I am looking if we are looking for apples, it only gives a match when it gets anything other than Apple